# Fortran, parameters and static table inside a derived data type

Tags: fortran, derived-types

I would like to create a derived data type which contains a table and the length of this table. Ideally, I would like to declare it as follow

```
type mydata
    integer                :: ndata
    real, dimension(ndata) :: x
end type mydata
```

But at the beginning ndata is not known and thus x is a dynamic table.

Do I have to use `allocatable` for x and allocate it when ndata is known ?

```
type mydata
    integer                         :: ndata
    real, dimension(:), allocatable :: x
end type mydata

....

type(mydata) :: var
var % ndata = 10
allocate(var % x(10))
```

What is the best way to manage such cases ?

Answer (score 6):

The best way to solve your problem would be to use a bang-up-to-date Fortran 2003 compliant compiler and use a *parameterised derived type*.  If memory serves me well only the Cray and IBM compilers currently support this feature.  It would allow you to define a type like this

```
type mydata(sz)
    integer, len :: sz
    real, dimension(sz) :: x
end type mydata
```

which seems to be exactly what you want.  If you don't have either of those compilers then workarounds, such as the one you propose, will have to satisfy you for the time being.  You could, of course, bundle your preferred workaround into a non-default type constructor.

If you are stuck without parameterised derived types then I'd start with a type definition like this:

```
type mydata
    real, dimension(:), allocatable :: x
  contains
    procedure :: setSize
    procedure :: getSize
end type mydata
```

and define those type-bound procedures in the obvious (?) way.  This would prevent `ndata` and the size of `x` becoming different.

Comment: I am not really familiar with OOP in fortran and I do not understand what you call "a non-default type constructor". Do you mean a simple subroutine which fill in the structure ? However, your last example is elegant. It is a good think to bind `ndata` and the length of `x`, but how should I define those procedure ?  Are they simply standard subroutine in the same module than the structure ?

Comment: It seems you are well motivated to learn some more of the OOP features of Fortran.  The book by Metcalf, Reid and Cohen has good, if terse, coverage.  Type (or structure) constructors (default and non-default) share the name of the type, e.g. `object = mydata(2,[0.3,0.4])`; you'll need to define an interface called `mydata` and routines which implement the interface.  Define `getSize` and `setSize` as you would any other procedure but investigate the `pass` binding attribute.  When you get stuck, ask further questions.